# All WMS layers not showing in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers, wms, layers, overlapping-features

I'm trying to display information on OpenLayers from different sources, I guess the problem is that some of these layers has information for the same areas as another layer already has. And OpenLayers doesn't allow overlapping of layers?

I found something about setting "allOverlays=true" should do the trick, but nothing changes. When display the layers one by one everything works fine. I just can't combine them.

Here's my code:

```
var layers = [

    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    }),
    new ol.layer.Image({
      source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
        url: 'http://localhost:80/WMSServer1',
        params: {'LAYERS': 'buildings,restrictedarea'},
        ratio: 1
      })
    }),

            new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    }),
    new ol.layer.Image({
      source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
        url: 'http://localhost:80/WMSServer2',
        params: {'LAYERS': 'areas,parks,buildings'},
        ratio: 1
      })
    }),

    new ol.layer.Image({
      source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
        url: 'http://localhost:80/WMSServer3',
        params: {'LAYERS': 'areas'},
        ratio: 1
      })
    })

  ];
  var userPos = "";
    if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
          do_something(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
        });
    } else {
      /* geolocation IS NOT available */
    }

  var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: layers,
    target: 'map',
    allOverlays:true, 
    view: new ol.View({
      center: [-10997148, 4569099],
      zoom: 4
    })
  });

  var lonLat = new ol.LonLat( -0.1279688 ,51.5077286 )
      .transform(
        new ol.Projection("EPSG:4326"), // transform from WGS 1984
        map.getProjectionObject() // to Spherical Mercator Projection
      );

var zoom=16;
var markers = new ol.Layer.Markers( "Markers" );
map.addLayer(markers);
markers.addMarker(new ol.Marker(lonLat));
map.setCenter (lonLat, zoom);



    if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
          do_something(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
        });
    } else {
      /* geolocation IS NOT available */
    }
    function do_something(latUser,longUser){
        var newCoord = ol.proj.transform([longUser, latUser], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
        console.log(newCoord);
        map.setView(new ol.View({
                center: newCoord,
                zoom: 10
         }));


    }
```

Comment: You can overlay as many WMS layers as you like but if they have the same extent, you'll only see the top layer unless you have transparency set.

Comment: Maybe related: You added an OSM layer twice in your layers array. This will probably block the WMSServer1 layer you've added.

Answer (score 1):

As [@nmtoken](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/27874/nmtoken) mentioned, if you want to see multiple imageWMS at a time you should set transparencies of layers.
I wrote a sample for it.

I have two image wms: [imageWms1](https://ahocevar.com/geoserver/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=ne%3ANE1_HR_LC_SR_W_DR&CRS=EPSG%3A3857&STYLES=&WIDTH=658&HEIGHT=355&BBOX=-13888944.635145342%2C2867630.7173607955%2C-7451112.364854658%2C6340929.2826392045) and [imageWms2](https://ahocevar.com/geoserver/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=topp%3Astates&CRS=EPSG%3A3857&STYLES=&WIDTH=658&HEIGHT=355&BBOX=-13888944.635145342%2C2867630.7173607955%2C-7451112.364854658%2C6340929.2826392045)

[**Sample code is here.**](https://codepen.io/himyata/pen/prWNMQ)

```
var osm=new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM()
  });

var imageWms2=new ol.layer.Image({
    extent: [-13884991, 2870341, -7455066, 6338219],
    source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
      url: 'https://ahocevar.com/geoserver/wms',
      params: {'LAYERS': 'topp:states'},
      ratio: 1,
      serverType: 'geoserver'
    }),
    opacity: 0.5
  });

var imageWms1=new ol.layer.Image({
    extent: [-13884991, 2870341, -7455066, 6338219],
    source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
      url: 'https://ahocevar.com/geoserver/wms',
      params: {'LAYERS': 'ne:NE1_HR_LC_SR_W_DR'},
      ratio: 1,
      serverType: 'geoserver'
    })
  });

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [osm, imageWms1, imageWms2],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [-10997148, 4569099],
    zoom: 4
  })
});
```